# Prove that $x^3+12x^2+18x+6$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $x^3+12x^2+18x+6$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Note: It has been a minute since I have done a problem like this.

I am told to use Eisenstein's Criterion. So I need to find a prime, p, that divides 12, 18, and 6 but $p^2$ doesn't divide 6. Well I can see that p can be either 2 or 3. Does it matter whether I use 2 or 3?

Also is this enough for the proof?

Comment: $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ is not prime.

Comment: But if I use 3 then I would be fine right?

Comment: Yes,  $3$ would work.

Comment: @KentaS So would my argument with 3 be enough for the proof? I get this nagging feeling I need to say more......

Comment: Yes, that would be enough. (Also note that $p=1+i$ doesn't work since $(1+i)^2=2i|6$.)

Comment: Thanks for helping!!!